# angular open $uibModal on ng-blur gives Unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs

I have a input field

```
<input name="email" ng-model="vm.newOrder.email"
 required autofocus ng-blur="vm.getUser(vm.newOrder.email)"/>
```

And I want to call a function on field blur, checking if user with this email exists. And if not, I am trying to open a dialog.

```
       function getUser(email) {
        if (vm.buyerForm.email.$valid && email !== '') {
            return siteAuthService.getUserByEmail(email, params.serverId)
                .then((respUser) => {
                       ...
                       //bla
                    }
                    else {
                        vm.isUserExists = false;
                       // createAccountDialog(email);
                        var modal = $uibModal.open({
                            template: require('../../dialogs/formOrderDialog/newSiteUserDialog.tmpl.html'),
                            controller: 'newSiteUserDialogController',
                            controllerAs: 'vm',
                            resolve: {
                                email: vm.newOrder.email,
                                phone: vm.newOrder.phone,
                                server: params.serverId
                            }

                        });
                        modal.result.then((usr => {
                            vm.isUserExists = usr.created;
                            if (usr.phone) {
                                vm.newOrder.phone = usr.phone;
                            }
                            //  if(usr.)
                        }));

                    }
                });
        }
```

But in the case user doesn't exist I am getting an error on the $uibModal.open line:

```
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: test@email.comProvider <- test@email.com
```

With the email field value. I don't really get what this error is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the resolve object:

```
 resolve: {
           user: function () {
           return {
                   email: vm.newOrder.email,
                   phone: vm.newOrder.phone,
                   server: params.serverId
                };
              }
         }
```